# Is that possible or not that getting the browser's timezone when paste the url in browser search bar and hit "Enter" Key or that url is "clicked"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

in my laravel application, i have generated a link. I will copied and give it to another person from skype or messenger etc. I want to get browser's timezone and give that timezone value in the url parameter using javascript when a person pasted that url in browser search bar and hit "Enter" key.

Is that possible? If possible, let me know how can i get it.

try to get time zone when click that link using jquery but not ok when paste the generated link in browser search bar

Comment: `when click that link` ... what link is "that link"?

Comment: that link means generated link,

Comment: oh, *i have generated a link* ... can you show an example of how you generate the link you generated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sorry for my sentence, 
the generated link is like follow,
http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/8549dqewr1-8618-43c3-b052-62fc123412c
and then i will copy that link and paste another browser and press Enter, and then the specific page will show. This specific page is written in laravel blade.
In that page, i want to show the date time according according to browser's timezone. 

my question is that is it possible when paste the generated link in the browser's search bar and press Enter, browser's the time-zone is retrieve and carry to server side. set that time-zone in session and use in blade?